# Resolve host + sub-directory url in PHP

Tags: php

What I want is to be able to get the host and the sub-folder of a particular site. For example:
get `http://example:81/test/` from `http://example:81/test/pagename.php`.

It should also work with same url `http://example:81/test/` and with multiple levels of sub-folders such as `http://example:81/test/test2/somepage.php`.

It should not get the structure of the file within a folder itself such as `http://example:81/test/images/page.php` should still be `http://example:81/test/` and not `http://example:81/test/images/`.

I tried using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] // only provides example:81
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] // provides full path example:81/test/images/
```

Essentially I want to get is the url of the index.php file even if it is in a sub-folder.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try to do that with regular expression, can't think of anything simpler

Comment: How can you make a difference between a subdomain and a simple sub-directory like `images` ? `parse_url` will allow you to extract all parts of the URL but it will not know if its a sub domain or a simple directory, these function work on string, that's all.

Comment: @MatRt subdomain comes before the domain and a sub-directory comes after /. for example `test.example.com/foo/bar.php`, `test` is the subdomain part for host `test.example.com` and `/foo/` is the subdirectory.

Comment: Unelss this is for your own site, it's a somewhat pointless exercises. URL paths do not have to correspond in ANY WAY to actual server-side file-system paths. e.g. `http://example.com/1/2/3` could very well actually be run by a script `root.php?x=1&y=2&z=3`, with no `/1/2/3` directories on the server at all.

Comment: have you tried $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] ?

Comment: @MarcB Reason I want this is so I could easily move the entire site(it's database-less) to a sub-folder for testing for example.

Comment: @rncrtr I tried but what I get is this: /var/services/web/site/test/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to build your own string to get the full url.

```
<?php
$url = 'http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'s':'').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If you want details from that, you can use parse_url()

```
<?php
$details = parse_url($url);
print_r($details);
```

would output something like:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [port] => 81
    [path] => /test/test2/
    [query] => somepage.php
)
```

Edit:

If you want the path to the file, you can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SCRIPT']` to get the filename of the called script relative to the document root or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` to get the server path including the document root. There are also the built in constants `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` that have the server path up to the current script, even when included. All of these can be used with dirname() to get the directory of the variable and basename() to get just the filename. There is also `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that has the path up to the web root.

So to get a path under the same directory this script resides in, if the script `/var/www/test/index.php` is called, you can use `dirname(__FILE__).'/some/sub/dir/'`.

You can see all the server variables by just doing a print_r of `$_SERVER` or even better you can call `phpinfo()` to get a nice output of all defined php modules and variables.

Comment: I guess my question was too specific to answer fully(without all my code posted). Your answer was very helpful though. Is there a tydier way to express first code sample, or is it by far the "best" way as it is? Also, $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] is returned with port already so if I use your code as it is I get duplicate port, any way around this, or do I even need to worry since maybe port is always included in the http_host?

Comment: @DominicM That is the only way I know. And I don't have a server on a non-standard port so I didn't know the port was included with `HTTP_HOST`. You can remove the port part (I'll edit and remove it). If you don't need to switch between http/https you can remove the check for https also. You can see other examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem in a project of mine; i wanted to be able to get the `subfolder` via a script filename (etc. **index.php**)
I tried some methods but the following (ugly) method worked.
The trick is to "feed" the method with all the possible "places" that all .php files can exist.

If the `script name` is found into one of these places, then `subtract` the part **LEFT** of 
those places; this part should be the `subfolder` (if there's any).

Yes, its ugly but worked for me...

```
$string = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$subfolder = NULL;
// tries to find the 'subfolder' by checking all possible PHP calls
$places = array("/","plugins/","system/php");
foreach($places as $key=>$val) {
   $pos = strpos($string,$val);
   if ($pos !== FALSE && !isset($subfolder)) {
     $subfolder = substr($string,0,$pos-1);
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I ended up simply subtracting the link names that I had in an array from the current url then appending it to the end if it's not currently selected link.